# splitting numpy based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

I need to split a 3D numpy array depending on the value of the Numpy array in the 3rd column. So suppose 3rd column has value 0,1 and 2, then I need 3 2d numpy arrays one which was having value 0, the other 1 and so on.

I tried with `numpy.where` but not successful.

This is a sample of my data:

```
(165, 69, 3)
(165, 70, 3)
(165, 71, 3)
(165, 72, 3)
(211, 416, 4)
(211, 417, 4)
(211, 418, 4)
(211, 419, 4)
(211, 420, 4)
(211, 421, 4)
(211, 422, 4)
```

so in this case I need two arrays, one array having value 3 and the other 4.

Answer (score 3):

for a general solution you can us [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_index=True`, then use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html), like this:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [(165, 69, 3),
     (165, 70, 3),
     (165, 71, 3),
     (165, 72, 3),
     (211, 416, 4),
     (211, 417, 4),
     (211, 418, 4),
     (211, 419, 4),
     (211, 420, 4),
     (211, 421, 4),
     (211, 422, 4)])

a = a[a[:, 2].argsort()]
third_col = a[:, 2]

_, indices = np.unique(third_col, return_index=True)
result = np.split(a, indices)[1:]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[array([[165,  69,   3],
       [165,  70,   3],
       [165,  71,   3],
       [165,  72,   3]]),
array([[211, 416,   4],
       [211, 417,   4],
       [211, 418,   4],
       [211, 419,   4],
       [211, 420,   4],
       [211, 421,   4],
       [211, 422,   4]])]
```

Comment: Can you explain why did you do `a[a[:, 2].argsort()]` please ?

Comment: @DorianTurba so `np.unique`'s indices will have a single index per unique value. I could also construct the result based on both return values) values and indices, but this seemed a little simpler.

Comment: Ok, I doesn't know that it is possible to get a list of a list using `list_1 = list_2[[index_list]]`

Answer (score -1):

let d be your array:

```
d[numpy.where(d[:,-1]==3)]
```

gives all lines with 3 as last element.

Answer (score -1):

This does what you are looking for:

```python
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[165, 69, 3], [165, 70, 3], [165, 71, 3], [165, 72, 3], [211, 416, 4], [211, 417, 4], [211, 418, 4], [211, 419, 4], [211, 420, 4], [211, 421, 4], [211, 422, 4]])

arr1 = arr[np.where(arr[:,2] == 3)]
arr2 = arr[np.where(arr[:,2] == 4)]

print(arr1)
print(arr2)
```

Comment: Hi Gilad, thanks for your response but am getting the below error:
arr1 = coordinates_true[np.where(coordinates_true[:,2] == 3)]

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: I can run this code in both python 2 and python 3. I am running numpy version 1.16.4. Are you running updated versions?

Maybe the problem is with copy pasting the `arr` declaration. Try to delete the new line in the middle